# Issue with Docker Image for Custom Deployment on Zyte (formerly Scrapinghub) Platform

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, playwright, scrapinghub

I am currently facing an issue while trying to create a Docker image for custom deployment on the Zyte platform (formerly known as Scrapinghub). My goal is to set up a Python environment with Scrapy, Playwright, Twisted, and other necessary dependencies.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11.6-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
    && playwright install --with-deps chromium  \
    && mv /root/.cache/ms-playwright /ms-playwright \
    && mv /ms-playwright/chromium-* /ms-playwright/chromium \
    && chmod -Rf 777 /ms-playwright

ENV SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE dummy.settings

RUN python setup.py install
```

And here is my requirements.txt file:

```
scrapy==2.11.0
playwright==1.39.0
Twisted==22.10.0
scrapinghub-entrypoint-scrapy==0.17.1
```

However, I am encountering the following error:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Executable doesn't exist at /root/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1084/chrome-linux/chrome
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright was just installed or updated.       ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers: ║
║     playwright install                                     ║
║                                                            ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                         ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have tried running the suggested playwright install command within the Dockerfile, but it seems that the executable is not being recognized. I suspect there might be an issue with the paths or permissions.

Any guidance on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

To be able to run my spider inside Zyte

Comment: Hi I recommend you using the official playwright image. [docker image](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker). Keep in mind to have the same version of the image and your local playwright installation. The image provides all necessary dependencies/libraries of all browsers. I verified the image and it provides python 3.10.12 (playwright:v1.39.0-jammy)

Comment: I already tested it but it doesn't work because there is a limit of capacity and it reaches the maximum size of 3 GB.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean the size of heap or what capacity are you referring to? If you reach maximum of heap then you can use [sharding](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-sharding#sharding-tests-between-multiple-machines)

Comment: Maximum size of the docker image that I’m to upload…

Comment: Ok, it seems your provider has limitations. You could take several approaches, but I don´t know if everyone works. 1. reduce the size of your image layers by using more install instructions --> more "RUN"s. 2. Exclude your project folder from image and mount it via volume. Probably your provider doesn´t allow that. 3. A dirty solution would be, you follow your approach by using the ```python:3.11.6-slim``` and open a bash to your running container, then run all instructions you need to install playwright´s browser dependencies ```playwright install``` and finish it by ```docker commit...```